# how to get number of days from the first day of the month using datediff

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to get the number of days from 1st of current month of current Year..to the current date.
so, what is wrong with this script? and the right one?

```
select DATEDIFF(day,CONVERT(varchar,1+'/'+ MONTH(GETDATE())+'/' + YEAR(GETDATE()),102),GETDATE());
```

Comment: Isn't the number of days from the 1st of the month always equal to `DAY(YourDate)` ??? On the 22nd of March, that number is..... 22, no???

Comment: @marc_s - I think it might be `-1` from that (since the posted code will return 0 on the first of the month)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: yes, possibly - you're right.

Comment: What is wrong really is that you use string operations to do date math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the number of days from the 1st of the month always equal to `DAY(YourDate)` or possibly `DAY(YourDate) - 1` ???

On the 22nd of March, that number is..... 22 (or 21 - depending on how you count) - no???

So how about this:

```
SELECT
    DaysFromFirstOfMonth = DAY(GETDATE()) - 1
```

Is that what you're looking for??

Comment: good idea-you are right, but how to use 'DateDIFF' with the same example?

Comment: @Salahaldin: **why** do you insist on `DATEDIFF` ?? This is just unnecessarily complicated and error-prone.....

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you use either [`DAY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176052.aspx) (as @marc_s says in a comment), or [`DATEPART`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx), to return an integer that represents the "day of the month" portion of the date that you're working with.

E.g.:

```
SELECT DAY(GETDATE()),DATEPART(day,GETDATE())
```

Will (today, 8th April 2012) return:

```
8,8
```

You can then perform any necessary adjustments from there.

Answer (score 0):

Your style value seems to be wrong. 102 is for ansi-dates (yy.mm.dd) - if you want to use british/french dates (dd/mm/yy) you have to use the value 103:

```
select DATEDIFF(day,CONVERT(varchar,1+'/'+ MONTH(GETDATE())+'/' + YEAR(GETDATE()),103),GETDATE());
```

see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '/' to data type int.

Comment: sorry I couldn't try this out, so I didn't see the other mistake: you should probably convert to datetime, not to varchar. But I think some of the answers below are approaching the problem much better